# Check if two objects with different structure are identical?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if two objects are identical, using `Pid` and `Vid`.. I know how to do it in PHP, but JavaScript is so hard for me...

```
// Object 1
{"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"6536025"}}]}}

// Object 2 (Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid)
{"1627207":"38330499","10004":"513661344","20122":"103646","5919063":"6536025"}
```

**EDIT:**

I did it this way, but it's really slow...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var details = JSON.parse('{"ConfiguredItems":{"OtapiConfiguredItem":[{"Id":"3657280986465","Quantity":"8674","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"839.00","MarginPrice":"839","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"839","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"128.84"}},"ConvertedPrice":"128.84$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"128.84","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"839.00","MarginPrice":"839","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"839","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"128.84"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"6536025"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986466","Quantity":"9878","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"869.00","MarginPrice":"869","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"869","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"133.45"}},"ConvertedPrice":"133.45$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"133.45","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"869.00","MarginPrice":"869","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"869","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"133.45"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266779"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986467","Quantity":"9989","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"889.00","MarginPrice":"889","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"889","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"136.52"}},"ConvertedPrice":"136.52$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"136.52","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"889.00","MarginPrice":"889","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"889","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"136.52"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266781"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986468","Quantity":"9995","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"919.00","MarginPrice":"919","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"919","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"141.12"}},"ConvertedPrice":"141.12$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"141.12","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"919.00","MarginPrice":"919","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"919","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"141.12"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266785"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986469","Quantity":"9994","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"959.00","MarginPrice":"959","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"959","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"147.27"}},"ConvertedPrice":"147.27$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"147.27","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"959.00","MarginPrice":"959","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"959","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"147.27"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266786"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986470","Quantity":"8993","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"869.00","MarginPrice":"869","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"869","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"133.45"}},"ConvertedPrice":"133.45$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"133.45","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"869.00","MarginPrice":"869","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"869","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"133.45"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"4209035"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"6536025"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986471","Quantity":"9687","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"899.00","MarginPrice":"899","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"899","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"138.05"}},"ConvertedPrice":"138.05$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"138.05","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"899.00","MarginPrice":"899","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"899","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"138.05"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"4209035"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266779"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986472","Quantity":"9932","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"919.00","MarginPrice":"919","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"919","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"141.12"}},"ConvertedPrice":"141.12$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"141.12","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"919.00","MarginPrice":"919","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"919","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"141.12"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"4209035"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266781"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986473","Quantity":"9959","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"949.00","MarginPrice":"949","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"949","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"145.73"}},"ConvertedPrice":"145.73$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"145.73","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"949.00","MarginPrice":"949","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"949","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"145.73"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"4209035"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266785"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986474","Quantity":"9965","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"989.00","MarginPrice":"989","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"989","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"151.87"}},"ConvertedPrice":"151.87$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"151.87","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"989.00","MarginPrice":"989","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"989","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"151.87"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"4209035"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266786"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986475","Quantity":"9409","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"949.00","MarginPrice":"949","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"949","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"145.73"}},"ConvertedPrice":"145.73$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"145.73","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"949.00","MarginPrice":"949","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"949","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"145.73"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"6630567"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"6536025"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986476","Quantity":"9661","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"979.00","MarginPrice":"979","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"979","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"150.34"}},"ConvertedPrice":"150.34$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"150.34","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"979.00","MarginPrice":"979","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"979","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"150.34"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"6630567"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266779"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986477","Quantity":"9911","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"999.00","MarginPrice":"999","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"999","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"153.41"}},"ConvertedPrice":"153.41$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"153.41","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"999.00","MarginPrice":"999","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"999","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"153.41"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"6630567"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266781"}}]}},{"Id":"3657280986478","Quantity":"9954","Price":{"OriginalPrice":"1029.00","MarginPrice":"1029","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"1029","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"158.02"}},"ConvertedPrice":"158.02$","ConvertedPriceWithoutSign":"158.02","CurrencySign":"$","CurrencyName":"USD","IsDeliverable":"true","DeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"OneItemDeliveryPrice":{"OriginalPrice":"0","MarginPrice":"0","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"0","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"0"}}},"PriceWithoutDelivery":{"OriginalPrice":"1029.00","MarginPrice":"1029","OriginalCurrencyCode":"CNY","ConvertedPriceList":{"Internal":"1029","DisplayedMoneys":{"Money":"158.02"}}}},"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"6630567"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"3266785"}}]}}]}}');

        var configs = [];

        configs[10004] = "513661344";
        configs[20122] = "103646";
        configs[1627207] = "38330499";
        configs[5919063] = "6536025";

        function updateConfig(pid, vid) {
            var id = null;

            for(var i = 0; i < details.ConfiguredItems.OtapiConfiguredItem.length; i++) {
                var OtapiConfiguredObj = details.ConfiguredItems.OtapiConfiguredItem[i];

                var current = [];

                for(var j = 0; j < OtapiConfiguredObj.Configurators.ValuedConfigurator.length; j++) {
                    var ValuedConfiguratorObj = OtapiConfiguredObj.Configurators.ValuedConfigurator[j];

                    current[ValuedConfiguratorObj['@attributes'].Pid] = ValuedConfiguratorObj['@attributes'].Vid;
                }

                if(JSON.stringify(current) === JSON.stringify(configs)) {
                    id = OtapiConfiguredObj.Id;

                    break;
                }
            }

            console.log(id); // Display result ID
        }

        updateConfig();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting `obj2`  to a `Map` and iterating over the `ValuedConfigurator` using `.every()` makes it pretty simple.

```js
// Object 1
const obj1 = {"Configurators":{"ValuedConfigurator":[{"@attributes":{"Pid":"1627207","Vid":"38330499"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"10004","Vid":"513661344"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"20122","Vid":"103646"}},{"@attributes":{"Pid":"5919063","Vid":"6536025"}}]}}

// Object 2 (Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid,Pid:Vid)
const obj2 = {"1627207":"38330499","10004":"513661344","20122":"103646","5919063":"6536025"}

const vc = obj1.Configurators.ValuedConfigurator;
const m = new Map(Object.entries(obj2));

const areEqual = vc.length == m.size &&
                 vc.every(({"@attributes":{Pid, Vid}}) => m.get(Pid) === Vid);

console.log(areEqual);
```